# ServiceStack Locode Multi select option

Tags: servicestack

I am developing an app and got a feature where an user can assign multiple **User**'s  to a **Feature** . I want the Create Feature page (**locode**) to populate the list of available users so that the end-user can assign multiple `users` to a `feature`. As of now it is not able to populate the User list.

Is there an alternate way or do I need to write the custom template and populate the data on `mount()` lifecycle?

Below is the DTO,

```
[Route("/feature", "POST")]
    public class CreateFeatureFlag : ICreateDb<Feature>, IReturn<FeatureCreated>
    {    
        [ValidateNotEmpty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        [ValidateNotEmpty]
        public List<Guid> Users{ get; set; }
    }
```

and the Domain `Feature`,

```
 [UniqueConstraint(nameof(Name))]
        public class Feature : AuditBase
        {
            [AutoId]
            public Guid Id { get; set; }           
    
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            [Reference]
            public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new();   
           
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Locode](https://www.locode.dev/) it would require a [custom Form component](https://docs.servicestack.net/locode/custom-forms) to implement it in the same form, but you can add related records by navigating to the child relation then adding the child record where it will preserve and prepopulate the parent id.

This is used a lot in https://talent.locode.dev like navigating to a Job's [Job Applications](https://talent.locode.dev/locode/QueryJobApplication) defined by its [POCO Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/reference-support):

[image: locode references]

```cs
public class Job : AuditBase
{
    //...
    public List<JobApplication> Applications { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Which will prepopulate the **Job Id** reference making it easy to add multiple 1:Many Job Applications.

Checkout its [Talent.cs](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/TalentBlazor/blob/main/TalentBlazor.ServiceModel/Talent.cs) DTOs for more Reference examples.